# Apache mod_rewrite module issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/?$ /?user=$1
```

I'm trying to rewrite
http://domain.com/?user=username into http://domain.com/username. Unfortunately this code doesn't rewrite anything. Please help

Note:
I checked `phpinfo()` and mod_rewrite is loaded.

**Update**

I need to get username from url like http://facebook.com/username. But this code rewrites every folder in root folder, so my /css folder become http://domain.com/css/?u=common. How to allow this code works only for http://domain.com/index.php

Comment: Does your URL look like `http://domain.com/username` which you are trying to rewrite to (actual URL)`http://domain.com/?user=username`?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey you think, that the issue is in wrong input and output order?

Comment: yes your RewriteRule seems to be fine. You are trying to access the URL `http://domain.com/username` from your browser right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you are doing is the use of `/` in the beginning of the line `^/(\w+)/?$`

rewrite rules strips off the `/` from the beginning of the pattern to be matched in `.htaccess` and directory context.

Try doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /?user=$1
```

From [RewriteRule Directive <sup>docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) :

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.
>
> ---

Edit: Answer updated as per OP's request:
Add this :

```
RewriteEngine On

#do nothig if URL is trying to access the folder CSS.
RewriteRule *css/* - [L]

#checks where the URL is a valid file/folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /?user=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are doing it the right way round, but explained it the wrong way round!

Is the problem that you don't need the initial / as the URL passed to test doesn't include it!?

I suspect it should be RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /?u=$1

Also, be careful you don't end up with a loop!